# Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$ and $R^{-1}$ is the inverse. Proof or counterexample

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$ and $R^{-1}$ is the inverse. Give a proof or counterexample for each of the following statements.

(a) If $R$ is reflexive, then $R^{-1}$ is reflexive.

Let $x \in A$; since $R$ is reflexive, $(x,x) \in R$. By definition of inverse $(x,x)\in R^{-1}$; therefore, $R^{-1}$ is reflexive.

(b) If $R$ is transitive, then $R^{-1}$ is transitive.

Let $x,y,z \in A$ be such that $x R^{-1} y$ and $y R^{-1} z$. Then by definition of the inverse, $y R x$ and $z R y$. By the transitivity of R we then know that $z R x$. Applying the definition of the inverse again gives that $x R^{-1} z$, and therefore $R^{-1}$ is transitive.

(c) If $R$ is symmetric, then $R^{-1}$ is symmetric.

Let $x,y,z \in A$ be such that $x R^{-1} y$; then by definition of the inverse, $y R x$. $R$ is symmetric, so we know that $x R y$. By definition of the inverse again, we have $y R^{-1} x$ and therefore that $R^{-1}$ is symmetric.

(d) If $R$ is antisymmetric, then $R^{-1}$ is antisymmetric.

Don't know about (d).

What about: Let $a,b \in A$ be such that $aR^{-1}b$ and $bR^{-1}a$. Then by definition of the inverse $bRa$ and $aRb$. But $R$ is antisymmetric, so $a = b$. Thus $R^{-1}$ is also antisymmetric.

Comment: Give a proof or counterexample of whether you have put efforts of your own in this.

Comment: Try the method you used for b) and c).

Comment: A small typo: in (a) replace "symmetric" by "reflexive".

Comment: one more "symmetric" to replace in (a) :-)

Comment: I meant to say symmetric the first time. Is that not right?

Comment: Never mind. You are right.

Comment: Looks good now.